# Razor: <text> tag within conditional statement throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@if (Model.Property != null)
{
    <text>
        <div class="row">
    </text>
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/CustomView.cshtml", Model);
    <text> (line throwing error)
        </div>
    </text>
}
```

Error: "The "text" element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag."

I struggle to understand why second set of `<text>` tags is returning that error. Any help to understand it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Razor, tags must be nested properly. `<text></div></text>` is not proper nesting.

I think in your case you simply should remove all the `<text>` and `</text>` tags:

```
@if (Model.Property != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/InTimeTemplate/InputFormElements/ReadMore.cshtml", Model);
    </div>
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
@if (Model.Property != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/InTimeTemplate/InputFormElements/ReadMore.cshtml", Model);
        }
    </div>
}
```

- `Partial` will return the result, which will be rendered thanks to the `@`
- `RenderPartial` will render it directly, but you need to introduce a C# block with `@{` ... `}`

Comment: I've tried to do that. Removing `<text>` tags is throwing "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' on HtmlHelper.RenderPartial. Everything is ok without `<div>` tags.

Comment: @Chris My first version of the answer was wrong, I copy/pasted a bit too quickly, try the updated version.

Comment: Sorted. Still forgetting to enclose HtmlHelpers between curly brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bit too late but still:

Just as an example u can use "@:"

Like this:

```
@for (int t = 0; t < Model.TrainLines[i].Stations.Count; t++)
            {
                <circle id="pointA" cx="@stationCounter" cy="@trainLineCounter" r="3" />
               @: <text x="@stationCounter" y="@trainLineCounter" dy="30">A</text>
                stationCounter += 50;
            }
```