# VisualStudio auto-format doesn't format my razor code correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using `@:</div>` to display some bootstrap columns correctly. This is the my code where i'm using it:

```
var i = 0;

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        @foreach (var one in Model)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:<div class="row show-grid">
            }

            <div class="one-element col-md-4">
                @one.Title
            </div>

            if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:</div>
            }

            i++;
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

It formats this (which works fine as long as i don't use the `VisualStudio` auto-format feature):

```
@:</div>
```

to this:

```
@:
</div>
```

And then the application doesn't work anymore.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Side note: I think it would be much nicer to group by 3 and render with normal Razor constructs instead of hacking with mismatched tags... But indeed it is an option.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sounds good. Could you provide an example or a link to an example please?

Comment: `items.Select((value, index)=>new { value, index}).GroupBy(x=>x.index / 3)` or many other variants starting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606945/how-to-build-batches-buckets-with-linq... Search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+enumerable+buckets

Comment: I used `Codemaid` http://www.codemaid.net/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using `@Html.Raw()` like this:

```
var i = 0;

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        @foreach (var one in Model)
        {

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row show-grid\">")
            }

            <div class="one-element col-md-4">
                @one.Title
            </div>

            if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</div>")
            }

            i++;
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess that this is as good as it gets.

But if anyone knows of a more elegant way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i get now, that i was wrong with `<text>` tag and [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408504/1849444):

> In Razor, tags must be nested properly. `<text></div></text>` is not
>   proper nesting.

The best way to solve your problem mention by @Alexei Levenkov:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        @foreach (var one in Model.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 3))
        {
            <div class="row show-grid">
                @foreach (var el in one.Select(x => x.value))
                {
                    <div class="one-element col-md-4">
                        @el.Title
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

But, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413999/1849444) your `Html.Raw()` approach is good enought.

Comment: You just copied `Alexei Levenkov`'s answer/comment. I think that he should get the credit. Maybe he will even write it as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

It's seem like the problem here is that you are opening a `<div>` on condition `if (i % 3 == 0)` but **you are not closing `</div>` on the same condition** `if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)`. 
This mean that you could have an opening `<div>` that never close or a closing `</div>` that never opened. 
 May be you can try this:

```
var i = 0;

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row show-grid">
    @foreach (var one in Model)
    {
        <div class="one-element col-md-4">
            @one.Title
        </div>

        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
           <div class="clear"></div>
        }

        i++;
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

May be this is where you are having trouble !
I updated on your comment. 
update on `@Alexei Levenkov` comment. I'm also looking at a better way of doing this. This solution is how i'm doing it in my projects when i need a 3 columns per row .

Comment: I know... But if i open and close the tag inside the if statement, how should i make the 3 columns per 1 row work?

Comment: I updated my code to reflect a 3 columns per line. This code works for me. You can clear row after 3 elements and this bring you back to a new row.

Comment: Consider removing completely unfair statement about correctness of OP's code... Also not that your change generates completely different markup than OP  - so I think downvote is still justified.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that this would work too, but it's not by bootstrap standards: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options i want the bootstrap code to be clean (without hacks).